# Still getting a black screen in pygame console while executing code

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pygame

Before posting this question I have read several other questions here in Stack but none of them seems to relate with my issue. Also I have read my code for hours trying to fix it but  nothing.

I really want to know what is wrong with my code and why I am still getting that black screen when I am executing the pygame code.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint

pygame.init()
ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,1000))
#abajo se encuentra el fondo de la ventana
#ventana.fill(ColorDos)
pygame.display.set_caption("Retouch")

Mi_imagen = pygame.image.load("Image/meflag.png")
Imagen_Dos = pygame.image.load("Image/Kool-Aid.gif")
posX= randint (100, 300)
posY = randint (101, 200)

velocidad=4
Color = (66, 133 ,244)#Azul
ColorDos = pygame.Color(244, 180, 0)#Amarillo
ColorTres = (244,67,54)#Rojo
ColorCuatro = (0,135,68) #verde
derecha=True

rectangulo = pygame.Rect(0,0,100,50)
print posY, posX

# Color = (244,180,0)
#primero donde, despues, color(tupla u objeto), tupla de cordenadas en X, Y. El ultimo parametro es el tamano del radio.
pygame.draw.circle(ventana, Color, (200, 300), 500)
"""Primero donde, despues que color, despues tupla con cuatro valores.
Los primeros dos valores (X,Y) son la esquina izquierda superior.
El tercer valor es el ancho de nuestro rectangulo.
Y el cuarto valor es el alto del rectangulo:"""
pygame.draw.rect(ventana, ColorCuatro,(100,100,100,50) )
"""Primero donde, despues color, despues el tercer parametro es una tupla con tuplas dentro de esta.
Dentro de esa tupla se encuentras las cordenadas, posiciones (X,Y) de los puntos que al final pygame une."""
pygame.draw.polygon(ventana, ColorTres, ((80,90),(200,400), (80,10))  )


while True:
    ventana.fill(ColorDos)
    # ventana.blit(Mi_imagen,(posX, posY))  
    ventana.blit(Imagen_Dos,(posX, posY))
    pygame.draw.rect(ventana, ColorTres,rectangulo)
    rectangulo.left, rectangulo.top = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
"""Este de abajo mueve a Kool-Aid"""
# posX,posY=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
# posX=posX-100
# posY=posY-50

"""Lo de abajo(comentado) mueve la imagen sin parar"""
if derecha==True:
    if posX <400:
        posX+=velocidad
    else:
        derecha=False
else: 
    if posX>1:
        posX-=velocidad
    else:
        derecha=True

#       elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
#           if event.key == K_LEFT:
#               posX-=velocidad
#           elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
#               posX+=velocidad

pygame.display.update()
```

How can I avoid this the next time?

Comment: is indentations correct in this code ? It seems `update` is not in `mainloop` so you don't send from buffer to video card (and on the monitor)

Comment: I agree with @furas. Try indenting everything starting with the "Este..." comment by one level, so that it all sits inside the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong indentations and `update()` is not inside `while True` loop - so you don't send data from buffer to video card and on the screen

```
while True:
    ventana.fill(ColorDos)
    # ventana.blit(Mi_imagen,(posX, posY))  
    ventana.blit(Imagen_Dos,(posX, posY))
    pygame.draw.rect(ventana, ColorTres,rectangulo)
    rectangulo.left, rectangulo.top = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    """Este de abajo mueve a Kool-Aid"""
    # posX,posY=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    # posX=posX-100
    # posY=posY-50

    """Lo de abajo(comentado) mueve la imagen sin parar"""
    if derecha==True:
        if posX <400:
            posX+=velocidad
        else:
            derecha=False
    else: 
        if posX>1:
            posX-=velocidad
        else:
            derecha=True

#       elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
#           if event.key == K_LEFT:
#               posX-=velocidad
#           elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
#               posX+=velocidad

    pygame.display.update()
```